# Any ways to improve this code used to scrape every table on this ASP page and store it into a CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is my source code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import csv

url = "https://opir.fiu.edu/instructor_eval.asp"
form_data = {"Term": "1171", "Coll": "CBADM"
             # Spring term, college of business administration
}
response = requests.post(url, data=form_data)

# URL for the table. Not sure if this is redundant?
url = 'https://opir.fiu.edu/instructor_eval.asp'
# grab the page
html = requests.get(url).text
# import into BS
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

#Need entire tables. So tbody, or maybe tr? for each row?
#Starting at row 5. We do NOT want rows 0-5.
rows = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class':'boldtxt', 'class':'questiontstl', 'class':'tableback1','class':'tableback2'})

for row in rows:
    print(row)

with open('studentevaluations.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
   csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
   csv_output.writerows(rows)
```

Much of this code has been suggested to me via Reddit by others. So what I am currently confused on, what I don't understand, is how to get specific rows from each and every table. I'm not sure if my code is correct?
This specific block is used to scrape:

```
rows = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class':'boldtxt',
'class':'questiontstl',
'class':'tableback1','class':'tableback2'})
```

Any thoughts on how to improve this so far?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much of the data you need to extract, you may need something like this:

```
rows = []
tables = soup.findAll('table', {'width': '75%'}) # tables = soup.findAll('table') works just as fine
for table in tables:
    trows = table.findAll('tr', {'class': 'boldtxt'})

    # this part extracts the header info from each table
    term = trows[0].text.strip()
    instructor, dept = [td.text.strip() for td in trows[1]]
    course, section, title = [td.text.strip() for td in trows[2]]
    enrolled, ref, completed = [td.text.strip() for td in trows[3]]

    # specifying multiple values for the 'class' attribute will search for
    # 'tr' tags having 'class' attributes of both 'tableback1' and 'tableback2'
    trows = table.findAll('tr', {'class': ('tableback1', 'tableback2')})

    # this part retrieves the main data found in the rows of the table
    for trow in trows:
        # if you choose to ignore the header part of the table,
        # make sure you remove the first part from this line
        rows.append([term, instructor, dept, course, section, title, enrolled, ref, completed]
            + [td.text.strip() for td in trow.findAll('td')])
```

Here's a sample output:

```
['Term: 1171 - Spring 2017', 'Instructor Name: Elias, Desiree', 'Department: SCHACCOUNT', 'Course: ACG   2021', 'Section: RVC -1', 'Title: ACC Decisions', 'Enrolled: 194', 'Ref#: 15164 -1', 'Completed Forms: 57', 'Description of course objectives and assignments', '0.0%', '64.9%', '14.0%', '14.0%', '3.5%', '3.5%']
['Term: 1171 - Spring 2017', 'Instructor Name: Elias, Desiree', 'Department: SCHACCOUNT', 'Course: ACG   2021', 'Section: RVC -1', 'Title: ACC Decisions', 'Enrolled: 194', 'Ref#: 15164 -1', 'Completed Forms: 57', 'Communication of ideas and information', '0.0%', '56.1%', '17.5%', '15.8%', '5.3%', '5.3%']
```